# Angular 2. Query builder GUI based on <table>

Tags: recursion, angular, query-builder

I need to create some kind of query builder with grouping and I'm trying to follow the TFS apporach (see pic).
Really like it to be organized as a `<table>` for dynamic resizing but I'm struggling with that. Recursion within `<tr>` and so on...
Has anyone done anything like that?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use a tree instead of table, especially as you need recursion.

Please check http://querybuilder.js.org/ it should provide what you need.